# wpf animation -- mouse down event doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, mousedown, coloranimation

There is a blue rectangle moving from left side of the window to right for different distance every time.

Either clicking the rectangle or the animation completed, the rectangle will start moving again from left side.

If rectangle is clicked, the color of it will turn to be green with a duration of 0.3s.

But the MouseDown event seemed not start the ColorAnimation and the moving distance/duration of rectangle was not correct neither.

```
private int i;
private Storyboard hitTargetStoryboard;
private List<double> disList;

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    disList = new List<double>{.......};  // init with a list of values.

    /* Create a rectangle */
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    this.RegisterName("rect", rect);
    rect.Height = this.ActualHeight;
    rect.Width = 50;
    Canvas.SetTop(rect, 0);
    Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 0);

    /* Fill rect with a solid brush */
    SolidColorBrush targetRectBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    this.RegisterName("targetRectBrush", targetRectBrush);
    rect.Fill = targetRectBrush;

    /* Add mouse down event */
    rect.MouseDown += Rect_MouseDown;

    /* Add rect to Canvas */
    myCanvas.Children.Add(rect);

    /* Create ColorAnimation to change color smoothly */
    ColorAnimation hitCA = new ColorAnimation();
    hitCA.To = Colors.Green;
    hitCA.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3);
    hitCA.Completed += HitCA_Completed;

    /* Create storyboard and add ColorAnimation to it */
    hitTargetStoryboard = new Storyboard();
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(hitCA, "targetRectBrush");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(hitCA, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));
    hitTargetStoryboard.Children.Add(hitCA);

    i = 0;
    TargetAnimation(i);
}


/* move the rect from 0--disList[i] */
private void TargetAnimation(int i)
{
    (this.FindName("rect") as Rectangle).Fill = Brushes.Blue;
    DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
    da.From = 0;
    da.To = disList[i];
    da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    Storyboard.SetTargetName(da, "rect");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(da);
    storyboard.Completed += Storyboard_Completed;
    storyboard.Begin(this);
}

/* If rect clicked, it will change color to green */
private void Rect_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    hitTargetStoryboard.Begin(this);
}

/* After color changed, rect starts over */
private void HitCA_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TargetAnimation(++i);
}

/* If rect not clicked, it will start over */
private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TargetAnimation(++i);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

delete :(this.FindName("rect") as Rectangle).Fill = Brushes.Blue;

add : hitCA.From = Colors.Blue;

ColorAnimation works well.

**Still:**

If I delete `Storyboard_Completed` or `HitCA_Completed`, the movement of rect goes well. While If I have both, the movement runs a wrong way.

**UPDATE 2:**

edit: `storyboard.Begin(this, true)` in `TargetAnimation(int i)` method.

add: `stroyboard.Stop(this)` in `HitCA_Completed` method.

without setting `isControallable` to be `true`, the storyboard will not be controllable.

**SOLVED**

Comment: It's a part of MainWindow class derived from Window. And Rectangle is System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle. @PetterHesselberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
(this.FindName("rect") as Rectangle).Fill = Brushes.Blue;
```

First of all, it would be much easier to make `rect` a field and set the `Fill` property directly:

```
rect.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
```

That wouldn't help your color animation, though. You've set up an animation to work with `targetRectBrush` -- which no longer fills `rect` since you've just replaced it. Removing that one line animates the color.

**UPDATE**

Here's a slightly tweaked version:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    private int i;
    private Storyboard hitTargetStoryboard;
    private List<double> disList;
    private Rectangle rect;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += Window_Loaded;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        disList = new List<double> {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };  // init with a list of values.

        /* Create a rectangle */
        rect = new Rectangle();
        this.RegisterName("rect", rect);
        rect.Height = this.ActualHeight;
        rect.Width = 50;
        Canvas.SetTop(rect, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(rect, 0);

        /* Fill rect with a solid brush */
        SolidColorBrush targetRectBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        this.RegisterName("targetRectBrush", targetRectBrush);
        rect.Fill = targetRectBrush;

        /* Add mouse down event */
        rect.MouseDown += Rect_MouseDown;

        /* Add rect to Canvas */
        myCanvas.Children.Add(rect);

        /* Create ColorAnimation to change color smoothly */
        ColorAnimation hitCA = new ColorAnimation
            {
                From = Colors.Blue, // (Instead of setting Fill to Blue)
                To = Colors.Green,
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.3),
                FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop, // Returns to Blue
            };
        hitCA.Completed += HitCA_Completed;

        /* Create storyboard and add ColorAnimation to it */
        hitTargetStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(hitCA, "targetRectBrush");
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(hitCA, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));
        hitTargetStoryboard.Children.Add(hitCA);

        i = 0;
        TargetAnimation(i);
    }


    /* move the rect from 0--disList[i] */
    private void TargetAnimation(int i)
    {
        i = i % disList.Count; // Don't overflow

        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation
            {
                From = 0,
                To = disList[i],
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            };

        Storyboard.SetTargetName(da, "rect");
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty));
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(da);
        storyboard.Completed += Storyboard_Completed;
        storyboard.Begin(this);
    }

    /* If rect clicked, it will change color to green */
    private void Rect_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        hitTargetStoryboard.Begin(this);
    }

    /* After color changed, rect starts over */
    private void HitCA_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TargetAnimation(++i);
    }

    /* If rect not clicked, it will start over */
    private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TargetAnimation(++i);
    }
}
```

What problem are you seeing with distance/duration?

Comment: I removed that line and the colorAnimation works. But I need the rectangle back to blue. What should I do with that?

Comment: Besides, the DoubleAnimation that moves rect doesn't work well after MouseDown event that the rect just stopped in the half way.

Comment: I've updated my answer, setting the `FillBehavior` to return the color to blue. I don't understand what your problem is with the movement; you explicitly call `TargetAnimation` when the color animation completes. If that's not what you want, you can dispense with `HitCA_Completed` entirely.

Comment: I just removed `Storyboard_Completed` and the movement of rect goes well. That's so weird ! But I need to let rect start over again after the animation completed even if the user doesn't click the rect.

Comment: Storyboard_Completed is the one that restarts the movement after it has finished. HitCA_Completed is the one that restarts the movement once the color animation completes. If I understand you correctly, you need to keep Storyboard_Completed, but remove HitCA_Completed...

Comment: I can't remove `HitCA_Completed` because after color changed, the rect needs to start over... So I called `TargetAnimation()` method in `HitCA_Completed`. Actually I need both `HitCA_Completed` and `Storyboard_Completed`. But there seems to be a conflict of two event? As long as I keep one of them, the movement goes well. While If I have both, the movement runs wrong.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "runs wrong"? Conceivably you need to stop any running animations before starting new ones. Here's a reasonably good read on controlling animations in code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741997(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, I realized that I didn't stop the animation. "runs worng" is that the rect stopped in the half way after I clicked the rect. I think I have found where the problem is. I start the storyboard without using `isControllable` parameter that caused the `storyboard.stop()` didn't work when I called in `HitCA_Completed`. So it should be `storyboard.Begin(this, true)` not just `storyboard.Begin(this)`. And the movement stopped in the half way maybe caused by the last clock of animation.